# Find complex roots of a simple exponential equation

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

It is known that solution of the equation $e^x=c$ is $x=\ln(c)+2\pi i n$.
I want to use above fact to solve the equation $a^x=b$.
So,
$$a^x=b$$
$$x=\frac{\ln(b)}{\ln(a)}$$
$$e^x=e^{\frac{\ln(b)}{\ln(a)}}$$
$$x=\ln\left(e^{\frac{\ln(b)}{\ln(a)}}\right)+2\pi i n$$
$$x=\frac{\ln(b)}{\ln(a)}+2\pi i n$$
But correct formula is $$x=\frac{\ln(b)+2\pi i n}{\ln(a)}$$

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you say that $x = \frac{\ln(b)}{\ln(a)}$ and assume it's the only solution, then you use that value in an exponential equation. Essentially you have two different things that you both call $x$.

In general, when you apply transformations to both sides of an equation, the next step is implied by the previous, because $x=y \implies f(x) = f(y)$. However, the opposite is not guaranteed to be true. That's why you need to check your solutions.

The correct solution to your equation would be
$$
a^x = b\\
e^{x \ln(a)} = b\\
e^{x \ln(a)} = e^{\ln(b)}\\
x \ln(a) = \ln(b) + 2\pi i n\\
x = \frac{\ln(b) + 2\pi i n}{\ln(a)}
$$